# Terrain rendering from bitmap in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, render, terrain

I have an assignment to render a terrain from a greyscale 8bit bmp and get colors to the terrain from a texture 24bit bmp. I managed to get a proper landscape with heights and so on, and also I get the colors from the texture  bitmap. The problem is that the full color rendered terrain is very "blocky", it shows right colors and height but it's so blocky. I use `glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)` but it still looks so blocky, almost like I can see the pixels from the bitmap. So any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use the bitmap as texture, or do you set vertex colours from the bitmap? I suggest you use a texture, using the planar vertex position as texture coordinate.

Comment: I doesn't use bitmap as texture, I set the colors directly from pixelvalues read from bitmap. I will try to do some code refactoring and use your suggestion. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you have to take into consideration is when you are rendering are you using GL_TRIANGLES or GL_TRIANGLESTRIPS this makes a difference on performance, second if you are using lighting you have to define your normals and each triangle or each vertex of each triangle, the problem then becomes tricky because almost every triangle is on a different plane. Not having proper normals would make it look blocky. The third thing that makes a difference is how big or small the triangles are; the smaller the triangles or the more divisions in your [x,z] plane increases you resolution thus increases the visual quality, but also slows down your frame rate. You have to find a good balance between the two.